# Adding multiple orders in one go

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a `Client` who can order products which are listed in the `Product` table. I want to show all the products in one order form.

**Like so:**

```
product A: [amount]
product B: [amount]
```

A client can add products to a daily order. So I don't need to bundle all the products as wherein the client_id and the current day's timestamp suffice to bundle them.

What I DO want is that a client can choose from a list of products and select the amount he wishes to order per product. So for every product the client adds a new order row should be created in the database.

How can I create an array of orders and POST them in one go to my order table?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this by passing multiple `ids` through to your controller from your form. To do this, you might have to break convention:

```
#app/views/orders/new.html.erb
<%= form_tag(orders_path), method: :post %> #-> should take to orders create method
    <% @products.each_with_index do |i, product| %>
        <%= product.name %><%= text_field "order[#{i}][#{product.id}]"
    <% end %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
def create
   if params[:order].kind_of?(Array)
       for order in params[:order]
           product = order.keys #-> outputs [array num, product_id]
           new_order = Order.new(product_id: product[1], user_id: current_user.id, qty: order[1])
           new_order.save #-> creates new row with product_id, user_id, qty
       end
   end
end
```

There's a good reference here: [Add multiple items to a cart at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581863/add-multiple-items-to-a-cart-at-the-same-time)

As you can tell, this is a little tricky; so I'd hope we can work to refactor this to get it to work

Comment: I'll ping you on Skype when I get into the office!